# Presence type unavailable with <show/>away</show> (away - resource is temporarily away) element not received

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, mongoose-im

I haave installed `mongooseIM 2.0.0` server on ubuntu.I have using smack 4.2.2 client library and backend database is postgres. When my app has gone to in background mode following presence stanza format i am sending to server

smack code

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
presence.setStatus(""+new Date().getTime());
presence.setType(Presence.Type.unavailable);
presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.away);
connection.sendStanza(presence);
```

send stanza

```
<presence id='aS7jX-85' type='unavailable'><status>1517400343535</status><show>away</show></presence>
```

In above stanza `show` element means resource is temporarily away that means user has connected on server but other rosters are appear that user last seen as a offline.

Above stanza received successful on `StanzaListener` but only once time.When user again request to get roster Presence type and `LastActivity` from that user it will give presence type is alway online.

The following smack `StanzaListener` i am getting `show` element

```
 StanzaTypeFilter filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Presence.class);

mPresenceListener = new StanzaListener() {
    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza stanza) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
        if(registerXmppListener!=null) {
            registerXmppListener.onPresenceReceived(stanza);
        }
    }
};
connection.addSyncStanzaListener(mPresenceListener, filter);
```

Following stanza format i am trying to get `LastActivity` from user

smack code for requested last seen.

```
LastActivity man = LastActivityManager.getInstanceFor(connection).getLastActivity(getEntityBarJid(user2));
```

Result

```
<iq to='sagardj@tasktower.com/13A843800EA34EF81517400323777798' from='demo2@tasktower.com' id='ncmqD-106' type='result'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:last' seconds='0'/></iq>
```

it will always give seconds=0 in `LastActivity` so i will again send request to get Roster presence type and i am getting following stanza result.

smack code for get `Roster` presence

```
Presence presence = roster.getPresence(getEntityBarJid((ActivityHelper.createJid(jid))));
```

Result

```
<presence to='sagardj@tasktower.com/13A843800EA34EF81517400323777798' from='demo2@tasktower.com/4A72251C2B957F841517400310999197' id='aS7jX-29'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='lWpWNgqtfynY+MxupmhOr2LZqOg='/><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' stamp='2018-01-31T12:05:16.000+00:00' from='demo2@tasktower.com/4A72251C2B957F841517400310999197'></delay></presence>
```

In above stanza result i am not getting away element.

we need any server side configuration ? we are following this link [Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP): Instant Messaging and Presence](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html) to send stanza request on server side.

Comment: remember if user added in roster list then after you will get presence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add `presence.setType(Presence.Type.unavailable);`. This signals to the server that the user is offline. If you want them to remain appearing online, but also away, then simply remove that line.

Comment: Thank you @sme Just remove `presence.setType(Presence.Type.unavailable);` line and send same stanza with mode `away` and `Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);` now i have getting `show` element.